# Cron expression hour 1/12

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, scheduled-tasks, crontab

I'm looking at a system where someone added a cronjob which schedule is like this:

```
0 1/12 * * * doSomething
```

More commonly, if the hours part in the schedule were `*/12` then it would execute every 12 hours.

What would be the expected behaviour of `1/12`?

Running Ubuntu version 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer suggest this syntax indicates increments. Now I've set up a test with this expression `1/12` on the **minutes** field:

```
1/12 * * * * date >> ~/crontest.tmp
```

If it would increment, then it would run on these minutes of every hour: 1, 13, 25, 37 and 49. But the results so far are:

```
Mon Aug 24 17:01:01 CEST 2015
Mon Aug 24 18:01:01 CEST 2015
Mon Aug 24 19:01:01 CEST 2015
Mon Aug 24 20:01:01 CEST 2015
Mon Aug 24 21:01:01 CEST 2015
Mon Aug 24 22:01:01 CEST 2015
Mon Aug 24 23:01:01 CEST 2015
Tue Aug 25 00:01:01 CEST 2015
Tue Aug 25 01:01:01 CEST 2015
Tue Aug 25 02:01:01 CEST 2015
Tue Aug 25 03:01:01 CEST 2015
Tue Aug 25 04:01:01 CEST 2015
Tue Aug 25 05:01:01 CEST 2015
Tue Aug 25 06:01:01 CEST 2015
Tue Aug 25 07:01:01 CEST 2015
Tue Aug 25 08:01:01 CEST 2015
Tue Aug 25 09:01:01 CEST 2015
```

If you'd use an expression like `*/12` then it would run on *"every minute that is divisible by 12"*: 12, 24, 36, 48 (0 or 60 included?)

So my guess would be that `1/12` would be *"every 1st minute of every hour that is divisible by 12"*, which is never, so it will fall back to *"every 1st minute of every hour"*.

And thus `1/12` in the hours field would run every day at 01:00 AM.

Answer (score 0):

#### What would be the expected behaviour of 1/12?

```
0 1/12 * * * doSomething
```

This means run at 1 am and then every 12 hours (1,13,...).

---

#### Special characters

> `/` - used to specify increments.
>
> For example, `0/15` in the seconds field means "the seconds 0, 15, 30,
>   and 45". And `5/15` in the seconds field means "the seconds 5, 20, 35,
>   and 50".

Source [CronTrigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html)

Comment: CronTrigger link is broken

Comment: @7ochem Thanks. I have updated the link.

Comment: I think your explanation is specific for the Quartz Job Scheduler. See my own answer with test results on Ubuntu 12.04